# Vue - How to pass parent ref to child as a prop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to pass current component's ref to a child component like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="screen" ref="screen">
        <child-component :screenRef="screenRef">
        </child-component>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    const Parent = {
        name: 'parent',
        data: {
            screenRef: {}
        },
        mounted() {
            this.screenRef = this.$refs['screen']
        }
    }
</script>
```

Since Vue.js types don't support `HTMLDivElement`, I am getting an error in child component when I define `screenRef` as a prop.

```
const ChildComponent = {
  name: 'child',
  props: {
    screen: {
      type: HTMLDivElement,
      default: {}
    }
  }
}
```

Could  someone please tell the correct way to do this?

Comment: `this.screenRef = this.$el`. `$el` is the root element of the component.

Comment: @EricGuan The problem is not that I am not able to get a `ref`, its that I am not able to pass it as a prop.

Comment: Why would you need such thing describe what you want to achieve

Comment: @GeorgiAntonov I want to use parent's ref in child component to do some width/height calculations. The thing is they are don't have direct parent-child relationship. There are multiple components between them through which data has to be passed. Though I can use class/id to achieve this but if there is some vue specific way I would like to know that.

Comment: Then why are you not passing the results of that calculation from the parent to the child?

Comment: @connexo There are 5 props that I need to pass through multiple components to reach that child (which are not at all needed in those intermediate components). That is why I am looking for a way to just pass a single prop and do those calculations in child component.

Comment: well pass the whole $refs object then if you really need it this way

Comment: @GeorgiAntonov Yeah, that sounds like a good idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Just try to access parent from child component via:

```
this.$parent
```

or

```
this.$el.parent
```

or use **inheritAttrs** option in child component for nontransparent pass of attributes from parent to child:

```
const ChildComponent = {
  inheritAttrs: true,
  name: 'child',
  props: {
    screen: {
      type: HTMLDivElement,
      default: {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is `inherit` documented?

Comment: You can find docs for it here https://012.vuejs.org/api/options.html#inherit
Oh yes, I just missed that it now calls `inheritAttrs` in v2. See here: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#inheritAttrs

Comment: `inheritAttrs` doesn't do the same thing as `inherit`, and is `true` by default.

Comment: yes, you are right `inheritAttrs` is just similar case of `inherit`(only for non-recognized attributes but not for data scope)...

Answer (score 5):

You do all the things correct. Just do not declare the required `type` for the `screen` prop in the child component. The following `props: {screen: {default: {}}}` will do the trick.

As side notes:

- The `mounted` hook **is** the correct place to assign the `$refs` elements to `$data` items as the former is not defined at `created` hook.
- Vue [has](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Type-Checks) `type: Object` that still would work well for your `screen` prop type validation if you want to apply the props type validation.
- If you by chance would want to assign the `default` object value other than the empty `{}` you have to assign it via function (unlike non-object data types):

  ```js
  default: function () {
      return {a: 1, b: 2}
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

If you need data from different component just pass it with props.

Or if you need this data in multiple components try Vuex:

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/

Answer (score 2):

This is a common issue when e.g. implementing infinite scroll, where you need a parent container's ref to set up an `IntersectionObserver` inside a child component.

This should also work: pass a `getScreenRef` function that returns the ref and invoke it inside the child's `mounted` method:

```
<template>
    <div class="screen" ref="screen">
        <child-component :getScreenRef="() => $refs['screen']">
        </child-component>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    const Parent = {
        name: 'parent',
    }
</script>


const ChildComponent = {
  name: 'child',
  props: {
    getScreenRef: {
      type: Function,
      default: () => ({})
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // by the time the mounted method is called, screen ref will be available
    const screenRef = this.getScreenRef();
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change default to null too and remove type. In my case I had to pass ref from sibling.

```
const ChildComponent = {
  name: 'child',
  props: {
    screen: {
      default: null
    }
  }
}
```